# jQuery - detecting when checkbox has changed

Tags: jquery, dynamic, checkbox

I have a range of checkboxes on my page and they will be dynamically checked/unchecked based on other dropdown options.

I can do this with

```
$('#first').prop('checked', true);
```

But i always need to detect whenever these change. I have tried:

```
jQuery(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    alert('checkbox has changed');
});
```

Which works when i manually check/uncheck the boxes but not when they are dynamically set. How can this be done?

Example can be seen here:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/humt4kww/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to 'trigger' the change event

```
$('#first').prop('checked', true);
$('#first').trigger('change');
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/humt4kww/1/)**